# C# datatype double not printing what I would expect

Tags: c#

C# datatype double not printing what I would expect

```
 namespace test
 {
     class SampleProgram
     {
         static void Main(string[ ] args)
         {
            int i = 10;
            double d = 34.340;
            fun(i);
            fun(d);
         }

         static void fun(double d)
         {
            Console.WriteLine(d + " ");
         }
    }
}
```

Why doe this produce 10 34.34 instead of 10 34.340 ?

Comment: Do you see differences between 34.34 and 34.340?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the computer a double with a value of `34.34`, `34.340`, `34.3400` are all equivalent and represented the same in memory.

What you are running into is the standard problem of the way the runtime gives data back is different than what to display to the user.  The way to handle this is to leverage one of the many formatting tools provided by .Net.

You could use the `ToString` method on the double data type with a custom format string:

```
double value = 34.34;
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("0.000"));   // 34.340
```

You could also use custom format string in [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
double value = 34.34;
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("The value is {0:0.000}", value));
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to apply a custom format to your double value, see string format options and example here
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx

e.g. number.ToString("G", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)